# Performance - iterating over vector with iterator or pointer?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, iterator, visual-c++-2012

I'm currently writing an application which needs to perform as good as it can be. I'm using VS2012 as my IDE (and compiler).

I've noticed, as I'm iterating over vectors, that a pointer solution in contrast to iterator, is much quicker in terms of speed. Why is that? I mean, an iterator is basicly the same thing. It should be at least.

Take a look at this example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
    // Do stuff with *it
}

for (int* i = &v[0], i <= &v[v.size()-1]; i++) {
    // Do stuff with *i
}
```

Is there any optimization that is needed by the compiler? I'm using all the standard settings, so -O2 is already enabled. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I'm compiling in Release, and running with Ctrl+F5 (without debugging that is).

**EDIT2:**
The actual source-code is an implementation of quicksort. [Here is a link to the full source](http://pastebin.com/529vY2p9), its very short so check it out.

Comment: You are probably compiling in debug mode, where iterators perform assertions.

Comment: Have a look at the difference between the assembly code produced by the debug and the optimised builds.

Comment: How are you profiling? What is happening in the loop? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest MSVC that comes with VS2012.

Comment: Check your settings for [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx).

Comment: Added a link to my source-code, there might be something iffy in there. Check it out.

Comment: @Eric In the linked code, how do you test with pointers instead of iterators? Do you have another similar function implemented with pointers? How do you profile? What is the performance difference?

Comment: My pointer-version differs in the partitioning-bit of quicksort (instead of using std::partition for iterators that is). I'm profiling just by measuring time of execution of the function call. The only differance is the partitioning-bit, and it results in ~30% slower for the iterator. http://pastebin.com/5KV2RWZA - theres a link.

Comment: @Eric But, that's completely different code!

Comment: While I don't expect any performance difference, consider the ranged for loop instead, as it should resolve to an equivalent of the iterator approach, while being shorter, grabbing end() once, and pre-incrementing.

`std::vector<int> v;
for (int const& i : v) {
    // Do stuff with i
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm currently writing an application which needs to perform as good as it can be.

Then grab a profiler and look where the real bottlenecks are. In optimized code (Release mode), of course.

-O2 is not everything in VS2012: there are several `#defines` that manipulate the behavior of standard container iterators wrt to bounds checking and other security checks. You might want to look them up ("checked iterators" and "secure SCL" might lead you to the right sites) and set them accordingly.

But I very much doubt that the iteration over containers will be your bottleneck, there will be other sections of code that are more sensitive to performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

One potential reason is that you are post-incrementing your iterator rather than pre-incrementing it. Try this instead:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
```

This may not increase your speed since some (maybe most) compilers optimize away this issue. However, sometimes when you post-increment, a temporary copy of the old iterator value must be made to allow it to return what you'd expect in the loop. It's something to try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to increase performance is not to do the `end` method on each iteration - also do `++it` not `it++`.

i.e.

```
std::vector<int> v;
const std::vector<int>::iterator end = v.cend();
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
    // Do stuff with *it
}
```

Comment: From actual measurements (with g++, not VC++), whether you use `++ i` or `i ++` is irrelevant.  Moving the call to `end()` outside of the loop _does_ make a measurable difference, however.  And in pre-C++11, using const iterators, it also may avoid a type conversion (if `v.end()` returns a non-const iterator).  For such reasons, I've taken to writing `for ( std::vector<int>::const_iterator current = v.begin(), end = v.end(); current != end; ++ current )`.